# Suppress vulnurability detection for single dependency

Tags: java, maven, owasp-dependency-check

I use the [OWASP Dependency Check Maven plug-in](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/) to scan my project dependencies for reported vulnerabilities.

- I have developed three projects that I scan, lets call them App1, App2 and and internal library IntLib.
- Both App1 and App2 has a dependency on IntLib.
- IntLib in its turn has a dependency on the external library ExtLib.
- The OWASP check reports a vulnerability in ExtLib, let's call it Vul1.
- As a result, the scan of both App1 and App2 also report Vul1.
- I have a global suppression file where I like to add a rule that suppresses Vul1.
- But! The suppression rule should ONLY apply when the report results from a dependency on IntLib.
- If App1 or App2 adds a *direct* dependency on ExtLib then the rule should NOT apply.

Is there any way to create a rule in a OWASP Check [suppression file](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/general/suppression.html) that works in this way?

Answer (score 1):

No, for this scenario you have to use different suppression files.

However I use a different approach.  I have some multi-module maven-based web applications.  Instead of scanning each module of each app (it would be time consuming and not necessary) I scan only the module that generates the final `war` (or fat `jar` if you use spring-boot) because this module inherits all the dependencies of the other ones.  If the check finds a CVE in one library, it is easy to understand where this library comes from: just examine the dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This doesn't really solve my problem but it is interesting to hear other peoples' thoughts about this.

Comment: Sometimes the solution is to change the problem statement. :-)